# React-native custom native module couldn't search header search path

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-native-module

I am building a wrapper SDK in react-native. However, I am new to react-native and facing following issues:

1. I have created a library using react-native-create-library npm package. While compiling iOS module it gives error that React-native bridge is not found.
2. I ignored the issue and integrated my code. When I link the SDK in a client app (created using react-native init), the SDK doesnt give the error for react-native bridge.
3. The existing iOS SDK is integrated via cocoapods in client app and I am trying to link it in the wrapper SDK via header search path. But whatever I try, I keep getting an error that the "module not found".

I am using Xcode 10 and Swift 5.

When I run pod install, the existing iOS SDK copies the files in Pods folder. I thought it should copy the framework file so that header search path could look up the headers in it. I have provided `${SRC_ROOT}/../../../ios/Pods` as recursive in wrapper SDK's header search path. But it didn't work.

Can somebody please help me with the issues? I have googled for sample codes and suggestions but none of them worked.